parameters in mysql or postgres for queries
I found myself having written the bellow code to be used to manipulate parameters of queries.
function prmstr($v){
    switch(gettype($v)){ 
        case 'integer':case 'double': return (string)$v;    
        case 'NULL': return 'NULL';     
        case 'boolean':return $v?'true':'false';
        default: $v=pg_escape_string($v);return "'{$v}'";// may be redundant to use pg_escape_string
    }
}

the idea is that I may use it like:
$p1=456;p2='A9XXP';
$qs="select * from tb where c1=$1 and c2=$2"
$qr=pg_query_params('select * from tb where c1=$1 and c2=$2',[prmstr($p1),prmstr($2)]);

or even
$qr=pg_query_params('select * from tb where c1=$1 and c2=$2',prmstrA([$p1,$p2]));

by defining accordingly prmstrA
The example to my understanding is the same for mysql.
I wonder if there is a different standard way to do it, or if there are counter indications as there are a lot of pg_escape_* .

What problem do you try to solve? When using prepared statements, you usually don't need to escape anything. Also, if your code should work on MySQL and PostgreSQL, maybe you should use any existing library for this, like Doctrine?

The escape is not the problem! An integer field is compared without encloding it in ticks like ' . While a string has to be enclosed idependently ffom escaping it or not!

The escape is the problem. When you use parameters, do not use pg_escape_string() and do not put quotes around the value. This means your prmstr() function is completely unnecessary.

Does the pg_query_params acts differently depending on the type of parameter, I mean when you say select * from t where x=$1 and you give for $1 the number 5 does it put around it ticks or not ?

A tick is a type of insect and just like bugs, you want to keep them out of your code. In your SQL statement you use placeholders like $1, $2, etc. The database knows exactly what data type should be used, but in some cases you have to use CAST($1 AS INT) when you didn't define the datatype yet. But you never have to use quotes ' around a placeholder.
